# How to decrease GAE usage cost?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, instance, billing

I am trying to avoid costs on my GAE accounts.
Previously my projects were running free of charge with no problems, but now Google required to link the payment account to be able to upload projects. Once I did it, I started to receive charges.

Yesterday, I've changed app.yaml settings to

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

and now yesterday's charge is 6 times more than day before.

Should I look at instances graph?
[image: instances graph]

Where could I see what I am charged for and how to avoid these charges?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to minimize cost or even avoid them for a very low workload, of course at the expense of user experience, I recommend you to use `automatic_scaling`, with `F1` class, and a maximum of instances set to 1.

```yaml
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
```

With [Automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#apps_with_automatic_scaling) your application can scale to 0 instances when there is no traffic.

With AppEngine Standard environment, you have a [28 hours free quota per day](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Instances). It means 28 hours x F1 class or 14 hours x F2 class...

With [F1 class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes), your instance will have the minimum amount of memory and CPU. In this case, you will maximize your free quota. So normally you shouldn't have any cost, at least for instances.